# phpmyadmin Error with php7: Missing json extension

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php-7

I'm using php7 with phpmyadmin on Linux Mint, which worked fine at first, but suddenly, when I try and access my local phpmyadmin instance, I get a "*The json extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration*." error.

Here are the fixes I've tried:

1) run sudo apt-get install php5-json

Result: get the response that the php5-json package is already the latest version.

2) Uncomment "priority=20" in all json.ini files

Result: they were already uncommented

3) Add "extension=json.so" to php.ini.

Result: no effect.

All of these fixes were followed by restarting Apache2.

Any input is extremely appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why you thought `php5-json` - the JSON extension for PHP5 - would be appropriate for PHP7...

Comment: php7 is supposed to ship with the php5-json package out of the box.  Thought it might be missing so I reinstalled it. Also, this is the most commonly referred to solution to this issue when searched.