# Installation results from php7 tar seem unfamiliar or incomplete

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php-7

I've been having some issues with phpmyadmin suddenly not cooperating with my php configuration, so I decided to reinstall php7 and phpmyadmin from the latest stable tar file on their respective websites.

(Edit: Here is a link to the issue that this is a sub-issue of: [phpmyadmin Error with php7: Missing json extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288257/phpmyadmin-error-with-php7-missing-json-extension))

When I uninstalled php7 (which was originally installed via this ppa: ondrej/php)
then reinstalled it via the tar file, the php files went into usr/lib instead of etc/ which I understand to be the default php directory.  Why are they being installed in usr/lib now?

Also, when I check this new directory, it seem to be missing php.ini and the apache2 service directory that php usually ships with.  Why is this? Do I have to install these separately now?

In short: Why does installing php7 from a tar file have such different defaults than the apt install of php5, and what can I do to make sure that something like phpmyadmin can understand and use this install of php7?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile from source, there are various configuration options to determine where files go.   The defaults for configure are not necessarily the defaults for a rpm or deb package.

Along with the PHP configure options: http://php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php, you have GNU general configuration options like `--prefix` to determine the install directory or `--sysconfdir` to determine the system configuration directory.

See all the options here: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html

> --prefix=dirname
>       Specify the toplevel installation directory. This is the recommended way to install the tools into a directory other than the
>   default. The toplevel installation directory defaults to /usr/local.
>
> --exec-prefix=dirname
>       Specify the toplevel installation directory for architecture-dependent files. The default is prefix.
>
> --bindir=dirname
>       Specify the installation directory for the executables called by users (such as gcc and g++). The default is exec-prefix/bin.
>
> --libdir=dirname
>       Specify the installation directory for object code libraries and internal data files of GCC. The default is exec-prefix/lib.
>
> --libexecdir=dirname
>       Specify the installation directory for internal executables of GCC. The default is exec-prefix/libexec.
>
> --with-slibdir=dirname
>       Specify the installation directory for the shared libgcc library. The default is libdir.
>
> --datarootdir=dirname
>       Specify the root of the directory tree for read-only architecture-independent data files referenced by GCC. The default is
>   prefix/share.
>
> --infodir=dirname
>       Specify the installation directory for documentation in info format. The default is datarootdir/info.
>
> --datadir=dirname
>       Specify the installation directory for some architecture-independent data files referenced by GCC. The default is
>   datarootdir.

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful.  I'm going to play around with this for a while will make a post with my results.

Comment: In order to change these config settings, do I need to recompile my php install or is there some way to change them post-hoc?